# Where to place my environment dependent gem config in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using a gem (RTURK) and right now I have the following code on the class that wraps the gem:

```
if Rails.env.production?
  RTurk.setup(ENV['AMAZON_KEY_ID'], ENV['AMAZON_KEY'], :sandbox => false)
else
  RTurk.setup(ENV['AMAZON_KEY_ID'], ENV['AMAZON_KEY'], :sandbox => true)
end
```

I want to move that to a configuration/environments/production and configuration/environments/development and test

But I am unsure at which point I should place the configuration of the gem. Does it need to be in a `config.after_initialize`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The environment files are loaded before any initializers (see [Rails Initalization Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/initialization.html)). This means that you can set a configuration variable in your environment file, and then use it in an initializer.

In your case, it looks like the only thing that differs is whether or not RTurk will be sandboxed. You can add `config.rturk_sandbox = true` to application.rb, and `config.rturk_sandbox = false` to production.rb file. Then create config/initializers/rturk.rb, which uses that value.

```
RTurk.setup(ENV['AMAZON_KEY_ID'], ENV['AMAZON_KEY'], :sandbox => YourApp::Application.config.rturk_sandbox)
```

(I'm suggesting adding `config.rturk_sandbox = true` to application.rb so that it does the safe thing if you forget to set that in an individual environment file.)